# How to find out which automation is running - iPhone logs

Tags: iphone, shortcuts-app

Every night I get the same notification about a shortcut which ran:

[image]

Unfortunately, when I go to shortcuts nothing relevant is shown there. I also disabled all shortcuts to see if it happened again and it did. Is there a way to dive into the iphone logs? I know that "console" on mac can show logs but you have to be connected the whole time with a cable. Is there a way to get logs from the device?

Answer (score -2):

Try Settings>Privacy & Security>Analytics & Improvements>Analytics Data. Some logs are stored here. Viewed on IOS 16.1.1